# PHP Query returns 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value'

Tags: php, jquery, sql, sql-server

Basically i send some data via an Ajax request to a php script which should run a query to update a table in the database.

However its been taking the text and note id i want no problem:
[image]
So i know its sending the data i want, however the table just isnt updating (it doesnt have the words "Additional text" from the data i sent there)

Now in the firefox Developer window under the network tab and under preview i have:
[image]
which seems to be throwing a sql error?

This is the php script run from the request:

```
<?php include 'connectionDetails.php'; ?>

<?php


if (isset($_POST['noteid1'], $_POST['notetext1'])) 
{

    $noteid2 = $_POST['noteid1'];
    $notetext2 = $_POST['notetext1'];

    $stmt = "UPDATE Notes SET Note = ? WHERE NoteID = ?";
    $params = array($noteid2, $notetext2);

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $stmt, $params);

    if ($stmt === false) 
    {
        die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
}
else
{
    echo "No Data";

}


?>
```

and this is the request itself:

```
function submitNoteText()
{
    var noteid = <?php if(isset($_POST['noteid'])){ echo $_POST['noteid'];} ?>;
    var notetext = $("#ta1").val();

    if(noteid == ''||notetext == '')
    {
        alert("NoteID or Text is blank");
    }
    else
    {   
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "submitNoteText.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {noteid1: noteid, notetext1: notetext},
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                alert("Success");
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
};
```

so i guess the reason its not updating the table is that error, so my question is how do i write the query safely in php without getting that error?

Comment: This is a SQL problem. The value you're sending cannot be converted to `VARCHAR` by SQL. Either because the value exceeds the bounds of the field size, or contains invalid characters

Comment: Hmm tried running the update in SQL itself and no errors, its a VARCHAR(MAX) so no risk of character limit

Comment: show your column design

Comment: NoteID(int), NoteName(varchar(40)), Note(varchar(max)) 

Also i noticed my parameters where wrong way aroound so i had noteid being declared as the note, however i swapped them and get a 504 time out now

Answer (score 0):

I think you've forgot the single quotes in `Note` column. Try this:

```
$noteid2 = $_POST['noteid1'];
$notetext2 = $_POST['notetext1'];

$stmt = "UPDATE Notes SET Note = '$notetext2' WHERE NoteID = ?";
```

Comment: but wouldn't this defeat the purpose of defining the parameter to make it safer from injections? I'll try it now quickly anyway